# Upgrading database on Application Update

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

I am having a database and i want to change that database on next update of my application ..But i dont want to loss the current data in database(in Application directory)..I have to copy that data in to new database and delete the old database..How can i achieve that?Is there any other idea about that let me know...

thanks in advance..

this is my current database code...

```
public class DbUtils {
public static String DB_PATH;
private String DB_NAME;
File dbDir;
private SQLiteDatabase dataBase;
public DbUtils(File fileDirectory, String sqliteFileName) {

    this.DB_NAME = sqliteFileName;
    dbDir = fileDirectory;
}

public void createDatabaseIfNotExists(Context context) throws IOException {
    boolean createDb = false;

    File dbFile = new File(dbDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + DB_NAME);
    DB_PATH = dbFile.getAbsolutePath();

    if (!dbDir.exists()) {
        dbDir.mkdir();
        createDb = true;
    } else if (!dbFile.exists()) {
        createDb = true;
    } else {
        boolean doUpgrade = false;

        if (doUpgrade) {
            dbFile.delete();
            createDb = true;
        }
    }

    if (createDb) {
        InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(dbFile);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }
}

public SQLiteDatabase getStaticDb() {
    return dataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}

public void closeDataBase(){
    if(dataBase!=null && dataBase.isOpen()){
        dataBase.close();
    }
}

 }
```

Comment: when you say: "change that database on next update," do you mean table schema changes? I'm just trying to understand why you want to delete current database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The more usual solution is to keep the database, but transform it as much as necessary to work with the new version of your application.  This is called "database upgrade".

You might be afraid that if this process fails in the middle of the upgrade, you will have neither the old database, nor the new one.  This can however be solved be database transactions.  If the whole database upgrade process happens in a single transaction, that transaction will either fail and do nothing, so that you can keep using the old version of your application, or succeed and you can use the new version of your application.

This is how to wrap your database upgrade in a transaction:

```
SQLiteDatabase database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(uri, null, SQLiteDatabase.SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE);
database.beginTransaction();

// put your database upgrade code here, for example:
database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD NewColumn int");
database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE AnotherTable ADD AnotherColumn int");

database.endTransaction();
database.setTransactionSuccessful();
```